# how to speed up extracting data from a large binary file in python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm pretty new to python and have been tasked with extracting observation data from large binary files  (this one is 470M, but they can be bigger).

My problem is that the data structure in the file means I need to read an element before I can establish how many times to read the next set of elements. I am currently using loops and calling numpy.fromfile() a lot, which is the slowest part of my code, taking the majority of the ~5sec runtime. I've been tasked with getting the time below 1 sec!

The file structure is as follows, with varying data types throughout:

1. Count of snapshots (N)

   - Snapshot information repeated N times.
2. Number of gridpoints (G)

   - Gridpoint information and data counter (C) repeated G times.

     - data repeated C times.

I am currently doing this for part 2 above: where dtype is just a stand in for the specific dtype used.

```
data = {}

data['Grid_Point_counter'] = numpy.fromfile(file,dtype2,1)

number_gridpoints = data['Grid_Point_counter'][0]

if number_gridpoints > 0
    gridpoint_data = []

    for gridpoint in range(0,number_gridpoints)
        grdpt_data = numpy.fromfile(file,dtype3,1)
        number_bt_data = grdpt_data[0][-1]

        if number_bt_data > 0:
                bt_data_block = numpy.fromfile(data_loc,dtype4, num_bt_data)

        gridpoint_data.append([gpt_data, bt_data_block])

data['Grid_Point_Data'] = gridpoint_data
```

If any of you very knowledgeable people can help that would be great!

Comment: If the entirety of that data is going to end up in memory anyway, consider just gulping the file in one go and then parsing that data in memory.

Comment: Other than implementing it in C/Cython, I don't see how you can do it faster.  `np.fromfile` is compiled and supposed to be `A highly efficient way of reading binary data with a known data-type`.  How big is `num_bt_data`?

Comment: @hpaulj: It may be possible that reading individual binary objects might be on the slow side though regardless of how fast `np.fromfile` is. It may fool the disc cache in to not helping much...

Comment: If number_bt_data tends to be a small number, you can make substantial gains by implementing this in cython or similar. If it tends to be a large number (say, > 1000), it is pretty much optimal and the only way to speed this up is by buying a faster SSD. 500mb in 5 seconds might well be hardware-limited depending on what it is you are running on; have you ruled out that possibility? Just because your drive may saturate your SATA connection under some circumstances doesnt mean it will always do so.

Comment: Thanks everyone. 
number_bt_data is between 0 and 300 in general, I may have a look at cython!